# I update the same video ID, but the youtube-api v3 still show "Video not found"

Tags: javascript, json, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I used google js api [Link1](https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=googleApiClientReady)and youtube v3 api [Link2](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/update)
I want use js to update my video, the js code for listing videos:

```
var requestOptions = {
playlistId: playlistId,
part: 'snippet',
//id: ['uY3InyzU79U','nOoHrAR50f8'],
myRating:'like',
maxResults: 9
};
if (pageToken) {
requestOptions.pageToken = pageToken;
pToken=pageToken;
}
var request = gapi.client.youtube.videos.list(requestOptions);
request.execute(somefunction());
```

The json response:

```
[
{
"id": "gapiRpc",
"result": {
 "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
 "etag": "\"Wes3wj_Yozi4a9GfHnpc8qG73KI/8qQBat1N6baCDG6C3Eed_XV_sZo\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 3,
  "resultsPerPage": 9
 },
 "items": [
{
 "id": "nOoHrAR50f8",
 "kind": "youtube#video",
 "etag": "\"Wes3wj_Yozi4a9GfHnpc8qG73KI/f7JZaoHeZG-CDYzXVRw2Q11Lins\"",
 "snippet": {
  "publishedAt": "2013-05-30T05:37:50.000Z",
  "channelId": "UCx0RClYCMhtsOXRlSyRcuRA",
  "title": "Webcam video from May 30, 2013 3:36 PM",
  "description": "",
  "thumbnails": {
   "default": {
    "url": "https://i3.ytimg.com/vi/nOoHrAR50f8/default.jpg"
   },
   "medium": {
    "url": "https://i3.ytimg.com/vi/nOoHrAR50f8/mqdefault.jpg"
   },
   "high": {
    "url": "https://i3.ytimg.com/vi/nOoHrAR50f8/hqdefault.jpg"
   },
   "standard": {
    "url": "https://i3.ytimg.com/vi/nOoHrAR50f8/sddefault.jpg"
   }
  },
  "channelTitle": "foretribe1",
  "tags": [
   "test",
   "webcam"
  ],
  "categoryId": "22"
 }
 }
]
}
}
]
```

the update video js code:

```
    var requestOptions = {
    part:'snippet',

    id: String(id),
    snippet:{ title: "ok update"}

};
    var request = gapi.client.youtube.videos.update(requestOptions);
    request.execute(nothing());
```

the request json：

```
[{"jsonrpc":"2.0",
  "id":"gapiRpc",
  "method":"youtube.videos.update",
  "params": {
  "part":"snippet",
  "id":"nOoHrAR50f8",
  "snippet":{"title":"ok update"}
   },
   "apiVersion":"v3"
}]
```

you can see here the id is the same as the list request json， but I still get the error respond:

```
[
{
"error": {
"code": 500,
"message": "Video not found",
"data": [
 {
 "message": "Video not found"
 }
 ]
 },
 "id": "gapiRpc"
 }
]
```

I also test on [Link2](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/update), but also get 500 error.

Answer (score 1):

You need wrap your updates in a 'resource' attribute:

```
gapi.client.youtube.videos.update({
  fields: "snippet",
  part: "snippet",
  resource: {
    id: "vid_id",
    snippet: {
      description: "updating vid",
    }
  }
});
```

Remember to set other attributes in the snippet (like categoryId, tags, etc.); otherwise, you'll get another error or they'll be unset.

Probably the best way to do this is to first retrieve the video snippet using gapi.client.youtube.videos.list and alter the snippet, then call gapi.client.youtube.videos.update passing in the altered snippet in the resource attrbute.